# android studio _ firebase _ storage _ get download url

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am working on Android Studio and using Firebase Storage, I could upload the images I want, but couldn't get the download url.

I used this:

```
askSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

and this:

```
filepath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

and the result was the same

it shows me some thing like this:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@f7d5815
```

my upload code:

FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;

storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();
      final StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("images").child( "test.jpg");

```
       filepath.putFile(selectedImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               bigImageEncoded=filepath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
               thumbImageEncoded=taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();

               Log.d("download_url",bigImageEncoded);


           }
       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  Log.d("erorr",e.getMessage());
           }
       });
```

Anyone can help?!! 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend that upon uploading any file, store the download URL to a database like [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) or the new [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) so it can be used later.

Please see below a simple example of getting the `download URL`.

```
storageRef.child("YourFolderName").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for "YourFolderName/YourFile.pdf"
        // Add it to your database
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: it works thank you so much, it was so annoying proplem

Comment: @aboahmad You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You need to listener to this event

```
filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(...{...})
```

and you will get uri in callback

Comment: it works thanks, it was very annoying proplem